# How to select multiple elements at once and add hover to them in CSS

Tags: html, css

How to select multiple divs and apply hover on them in such a way that when cursor is moved on each div, only respective divs gets hovered and not all of them together?

```
<div class="itemOne"> Menu Item One </div>
<div class="itemTwo"> Menu Item Two </div>
.
.
.
<div class="itemTen"> Menu Item Ten </div>
```

css:

```
.itemOne:hover .itemTwo:hover{
   /*this is not working*/
}
```

or

```
.itemOne.itemTwo:hover{
  /*this is not working*/
}
```

Comment: Your CSS code is incorrect. Try .itemOne:hover,.itemTwo:hover { ... }
Additionally there can be multiple classes for elements. You can specify a common class for all elements to reduce your CSS code to: .itemCommon:hover { ... }

Comment: read more about css! add coma between your CSS selector `.itemOne:hover, .itemTwo:hover, .itemThree:hover `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to seperate each selector by a comma.

```
.itemOne:hover,
.itemTwo:hover,
.itemThree:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

A more appropriate solution would be to add the same class to all those elements. eg:

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
    <div class='child'></div>
</div>


.child:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class to all the divs that u want to add the hover effect

```
<div class="hover-effect itemOne"> Menu Item One </div>
<div class="hover-effect itemTwo"> Menu Item Two </div>
...
<div class="hover-effect itemTen"> Menu Item Ten </div>
```

then add styles to that **hover-effect** class in css

```
.hover-effect:hover {
 //add styles here
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Give all divs a common class 
.commonclass:hover{}